# Invalid Syntax (Strings and Float complications!)

Tags: python

I can't seem to figure this out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
pitcherSpeed=float(round((40908/tempSpeed),2))
output=output+tempPitcher+ "\t" +str(round(float(tempSpeed), 2)) + "\t" +str(round(float(pitcherSpeed), 2)) +"\n"
```

I am having issues with the above two lines. No matter what I do to change them. They error out. I need some help determining what the heck is wrong with them!

Here is all of my code (if needed):

```
output=""
pitcherSpeed=1
tempPitcher=input("Enter the name of the next contestant, or nothing to exit: ")
fastestSpeed=0
slowestSpeed=0
if tempPitcher=="":
    exit()
fastestPitcher=tempPitcher
slowestPitcher=tempPitcher
tempSpeed=float(input("Enter the time for " +str(tempPitcher) + "'s speed in milliseconds: "))
fastestSpeed=tempSpeed
slowestSpeed=tempSpeed
while tempPitcher!="":
    output=""
    tempPitcher=input("Enter the name of the next contestant, or nothing to exit: ")
    tempSpeed=input("Enter the time for " +str(tempPitcher) + "'s speed in milliseconds: ")
    pitcherSpeed=float(round((40908/tempSpeed),2))
    output=output+tempPitcher+ "\t" +str(round(float(tempSpeed), 2)) + "\t" +str(round(float(pitcherSpeed), 2)) +"\n"  
if tempPitcher!="":
    tempSpeed=input("Enter the time for " +str(tempPitcher) + "'s speed in milliseconds: ")
    if tempSpeed==fastestSpeed:
        fastestSpeed=tempSpeed
        fastestPitcher=tempPitcher
        if tempSpeed==slowestSpeed:
            slowestSpeed=tempSpeed
            slowestPitcher=tempPitcher
print("Name" + "\t" +"Time" +"\t" +"Speed" + "\n" + "===========================" + "\n")
print(output)               
print("Slowest pitcher is " +str(slowestPitcher) +"at" +str(slowestSpeed) +"miles per hour")
print("Fastest pitcher is " +str(fastestPitcher) +"at" +str(slowestSpeed) +"miles per hour")
```

I receive the error message: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/whitney.meulink/Desktop/programpractice.py", line 17, in 
    pitcherSpeed=float(round((40908/tempSpeed),2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: Even without checking, one of the most common syntax errors in beginner code is due to unbalanced parentheses.  So start from the line that Python is complaining about and move up in the code until you find a forgotten parenthesis (usually `)` at the end.)

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
pitcherSpeed=float(round((40908/tempSpeed),2)
```

is missing a closing bracket.

```
pitcherSpeed=float(round((40908/tempSpeed),2))
```

It is often the case that the error is on the previous line.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/whitney.meulink/Desktop/programpractice.py", line 16, in <module>
    pitcherSpeed=float(round((40908/tempSpeed),2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'



See above error message. Sorry to bug you, I guess I just can't figure out how to make this work!

Comment: okay, one more question I promise. :P
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/whitney.meulink/Desktop/programpractice.py", line 17, in <module>
    output=output+tempPitcher+ "\t" +str(round(float(tempSpeed)), 2) + "\t" +str(round(float(pitcherSpeed)), 2) +"\n"
TypeError: str() argument 2 must be str, not int

Comment: `str(round(float(pitcherSpeed), 2))`

Comment: Gosh now its going back to:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/whitney.meulink/Desktop/programpractice.py", line 16, in <module>
    pitcherSpeed=round((40908/float(tempSpeed)),2)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: `tempSpeed` isn't holding what you expect. `print(tempSpeed)` on the line before the error and make sure it looks like a number.

Comment: it printed out a number.. :(

Comment: It continues to go back to the pitcherSpeed=40908/(tempSpeed)

Comment: if there is anyway i could get that to not error out... I would be so grateful :( I have no idea what I am doing wrong but I do not know why it continues to error out

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/whitney.meulink/Desktop/programpractice.py", line 17, in <module>
    pitcherSpeed=float(round((40908/tempSpeed),2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'